# Debugging 500 Response for Create Sales Receipt Through API Explorer

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I've been developing an IPP application using the PHP devkit. I've been using the XML returned from the $object->asIDSXML() method to debug my objects through the API Explorer.  Within the API Explorer I have been recieving a very ambiguous error when trying to create a Sales Receipt and I'm hoping I can learn more about the scheme requirements. Is there a validation xsd file somewhere? I'm currently unable to understand why I receive the following 500 code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <FaultInfo
xmlns="http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/baseexceptionmodel/xsd">
<Message>Internal Server Error</Message>
<ErrorCode>500</ErrorCode>
<Cause>SERVER</Cause> </FaultInfo>
```

The documentation regarding a 500 states something along the lines of :

Possible Causes:
Illegal permissions.
Illegal values that are not verified in the validation process.
Invalid data that the business logic verified.

I know that I have proper permissions, I have authenticated with an OAuth Token that has all privileges.  The later two possibilities I believe are the issue, but I don't know how to get any additional information regarding the potentially invalid or missing data.  I have literally tried creating a duplicate by using the API explorer to retrieve the SalesReceipt XML and then removing the DocumentID and sending to a create POST through the API explorer at which point I receive the same error shown above.

The following is the XML post data provided to the API.  As far as I can tell the xml contains all the required fields fore creating a Sales Receipt.  Thanks in advance for any help.

```
<SalesReceipt>
        <Header>
            <TxnDate>2013-04-16-07:00</TxnDate>
            <CustomerId idDomain="QBO">78</CustomerId>
            <TotalAmt>4.00</TotalAmt>
            <ShipAddr>
                <Line1>123 Fake Ave</Line1>
                <City>Fake City</City>
                <CountrySubDivisionCode>ID</CountrySubDivisionCode>
                <PostalCode>83854</PostalCode>
            </ShipAddr>
        </Header>
        <Line>
            <Id>1</Id>
            <Desc>Face to face IT Consulting Services, providing solutions to client's IT issues.</Desc>
            <Amount>4.00</Amount>
            <Taxable>false</Taxable>
            <ItemId>17</ItemId>
            <UnitPrice>4.00</UnitPrice>
            <Qty>1</Qty>
        </Line>
    </SalesReceipt>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please try the following

```
<SalesReceipt xmlns='http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2'>
    <Header xmlns:ns3='http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2'>
        <ns3:TxnDate>2013-04-16-07:00</ns3:TxnDate>
        <ns3:CustomerId>78</ns3:CustomerId>
        <ns3:TotalAmt>4.00</ns3:TotalAmt>
            <ShipAddr>
                <Line1>123 Fake Ave</Line1>
                <City>Fake City</City>
                <CountrySubDivisionCode>ID</CountrySubDivisionCode>
                <PostalCode>83854</PostalCode>
            </ShipAddr>
    </Header>
    <Line xmlns:ns11='http://www.intuit.com/sb/cdm/v2'>
        <ns11:Id>101</ns11:Id>
        <ns11:Desc>Face to face IT Consulting Services, providing solutions to client's IT issues.</ns11:Desc>
        <ns11:Amount>4.00</ns11:Amount>
        <ns11:Taxable>false</ns11:Taxable>
        <ns11:ItemId>17</ns11:ItemId>
        <ns11:UnitPrice>4.00</ns11:UnitPrice>
        <ns11:Qty>1</ns11:Qty>
    </Line>
</SalesReceipt>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That does help to provide some forward progress. Is it accurate then to say that there is no way of receiving further detailed information regarding the cause of the 500?  I'd really like to know how to trouble shoot this during development.

Comment: It generally comes when the xml(post) is not formed properly. I used the default xml from apiexplorer tool and modified the same with some test data.